# angularjs tests with es6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, browserify

I am using browserify to build my angularjs application with ES6 support, the application works fine but the problem I'm facing in running the tests with mocha and chai, how can I make the tests work with mocha+chai and import the angular module which is written in ES6.

or if you have a better approach, please advice.

Comment: What are you using to compile your modules for browserifying -- babelify?

Comment: yes I'm using babelify for browserify transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile the ES6 modules to ES5 CommonJS before browserifying, and then load those modules in your tests, or you can use something like mocha's `--compilers` option with `babel-core/register` or setup your own script that loads it. E.g.:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

Or:

```js
// init.js
require('babel-core/register');
```

```
mocha init.js ...
```

Comment: I made npm test script: "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register app/src/**/*.test.js" and in the project command line I entered `npm test` and I received angular.js ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: That sounds like a totally separate problem. You need to figure out how to test your code that requires a DOM. E.g. browserify the tests, run them in something like PhantomJS, ...